# How can I measure the time delay between a start and stop, and calculate mean/sd inbetween?

Tags: r, database

I am trying to measure the time difference between several start and stop points, but also take the average/SD of the Var1 & Var2 columns per start/stop period. These tables can be very long, but this is a sample:

```
Status  Time (s)    Var1        Var2
Start   0.05715238  0.7421875   -23.34501
Cont    0.08572857  0.7226562   -34.24408
Stop    0.11430476  0.703125    -34.24408
Start   0.25718571  1.3867188   -28.01136
Cont    0.2857619   1.3867188   -28.01136
Stop    0.3143381   1.3867188   -42.92692
```

I can get the duration by subsetting the dataframe by the Start and Stop variables, and subtract the end times from the start. However, this will remove the 'Cont', or continuation of the data for Vars 1 and 2.

How can I approach this problem in R? To generate mean/SD per start and stop period?

I would want my results to look like this (p=start/stop period):

```
p1_mean_var1    p1_sd_var1  pe1_mean_var2   p1_sd_var2  p2_mean_var1    p2_sd_var1  p2_mean_var2    p2_sd_var2
0.7226562333    0.01953125  -30.61105667    6.29258094  1.3867188       0           -32.9832133     8.61150258
```

I have a lot of these types of tables, and I want to summarize each of them on one row.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to start by getting your data into an easier form. You're working on the assumption the rows are ordered by period. Save that in the data.frame.

```
measures <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Status  Time        Var1        Var2
Start   0.05715238  0.7421875   -23.34501
Cont    0.08572857  0.7226562   -34.24408
Stop    0.11430476  0.703125    -34.24408
Start   0.25718571  1.3867188   -28.01136
Cont    0.2857619   1.3867188   -28.01136
Stop    0.3143381   1.3867188   -42.92692
")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

start_indices <- which(measures[["Status"]] == 'Start')

measures <- measures %>%
  mutate(Period = findInterval(
    seq_along(Status),
    start_indices
  ))

measures
#   Status       Time      Var1      Var2 Period
# 1  Start 0.05715238 0.7421875 -23.34501      1
# 2   Cont 0.08572857 0.7226562 -34.24408      1
# 3   Stop 0.11430476 0.7031250 -34.24408      1
# 4  Start 0.25718571 1.3867188 -28.01136      2
# 5   Cont 0.28576190 1.3867188 -28.01136      2
# 6   Stop 0.31433810 1.3867188 -42.92692      2
```

Because you want to do the same thing to `Var1` and `Var2`, it's easier to give them separate rows and handle them both at once. This can be easily extended to any number of variables.

```
period_stats <- measures %>%
  gather(key = "Variable", value = "Value", Var1, Var2) %>% 
  group_by(Period, Variable) %>%
  summarise(
    Mean     = mean(Value),
    StandDev = sd(Value),
    Duration = max(Time) - min(Time)
  )

period_stats
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Period [?]
#   Period Variable        Mean   StandDev   Duration
#    <int>    <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1      1     Var1   0.7226562 0.01953125 0.05715238
# 2      1     Var2 -30.6110567 6.29258100 0.05715238
# 3      2     Var1   1.3867188 0.00000000 0.05715239
# 4      2     Var2 -32.9832133 8.61150258 0.05715239
```